# Funcion de 2 variables de diferentes tipos de datos como resolverla?

Tags: mysql, funciones

Tenemos la tabla *estudiante* con los siguientes campos:

```
doc_est int(30)
nom_est varchar(30)
ape_est varchar(30)
edad_est int(11)
```

**Nos piden realizar la siguiente función:**

• Muestre el nombre y la edad del estudiante más joven.

No he podido resolverlo. ¿Alguien me puede ayudar?

Comment: ¿Puedes mostrar qué has intentado hasta ahora?

Comment: ¿Nos puedes decir qué es lo que necesitas exactamente? ¿Crear una función que muestre el nombre y la edad del estudiante más joven, o mostrar esos datos usando funciones (como `MIN()`)? Por tu comentario en otra respuesta me parece que tienes que crear una función. Sin embargo, si necesitas retornar varios valores, hasta donde sé, en MySQL no puedes usarlas, pues retornan un solo valor. Lo más cercano sería un procedimiento almacenado.

Answer (score 1):

Tienes que hacer un `INNER JOIN` con la misma tabla, pero usando la función `MIN` para obtener la edad mínima en la tabla. De esta forma la consulta te retornará sólo los estudiantes cuya edad sea igual a la edad mínima (pueden ser varios si más de uno tiene la misma edad).

```
SELECT
    E.nom_est,
    E.edad_est
FROM estudiante E
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT
        MIN(edad_est) AS EDAD
    FROM estudiante
) EDAD_MINIMA
ON E.edad_est = EDAD_MINIMA.EDAD;
```

**Fuente:** [Respuesta en "MySQL Select row with lowest value in column" (Stack Overflow)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20532121/1920523)

Answer (score 1):

Tu puedes hacer:

```sql
SELECT nom_est, edad_est 
  FROM estudiante 
 WHERE edad_est = (SELECT MIN(edad_est) FROM estudiante);
```

o

```
SELECT nom_est, edad_est 
  FROM estudiante 
 WHERE edad_est IN (SELECT MIN(edad_est) FROM estudiante);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
--Creación del delimitador
DELIMITER //

--Creación de la función

CREATE FUNCTION nombreEdad()
RETURNS NVARCHAR(50)
BEGIN

/* Concatenación de las tablas necesarias, para mostrar en la ejecución de la 
función*/

RETURN(SELECT CONCAT(NOMBRE, " ", MIN(EDAD)) FROM TABLA);
END //

--Llamada de la función creada
SELECT nombreEdad()//
```

Comment: Podrías ponerle alguna explicación a tu código por favor? Las respuestas que son solo código no son bien recibidas por la comunidad.

Answer (score 0):

Si lo que tratas es crear una función que siempre devuelva la menor edad, debes considerar lo siguiente, si haces un comando `INTO` dentro de una variable, esta solo espera **un valor**, por lo tanto si hay dos `estudiantes` con la misma edad la función no retornara resultado alguno.

Considerando

[image: Digamos que tenemos esta tabla]

Una funcion que acabo de probar y funciona es la siguiente:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` FUNCTION `estujoven`() RETURNS int(11)
NO SQL
BEGIN
DECLARE edadest INT(30);
SET edadest = 0;
SELECT
E.edad_est into edadest
FROM estudiante E
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT
        MIN(edad_est) AS edad_min
    FROM estudiante
) tabla_filtro
ON E.edad_est = tabla_filtro.edad_min;
RETURN edadest;
END;
```

Resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Ninguna de las respuestas da solución ya que lo que se busca crear es una función que al llamarla muestre el nombre del estudiante que es una cadena de caracteres y la edad mínima de un estudiante la cual es un entero.

en otras palabaras lo que se quiere que muestre al llamar la funcion es:

nom_Est      edad_dEst

maria           17

Comment: Hola y bienvenido!! gracias por la respuesta. Te aconsejo leer el [tour] y tambien [answer]. Estas seguro que esto es una respuesta? parece un comentario a una pregunta que tiene varias respuestas!

Answer (score -4):

Me parece que lo que buscas es algo así en `MySQL`:

```
select nom_est, min(edad_est) from estudiante group by nom_est limit 1;
```

El trick de agrupar `nom_est` te permite mostrar el nombre, puesto que `min` es una funcion de grupo.

Otra manera seria **(NO RECOMENDABLE)**:

```
select nom_est, edad_est from estudiante order by edad_est limit 1;
```

El `limit 1`, fuerza a la consulta a traer un solo valor y como esta ordenado, solo traerá el menor.

Comment: La primera forma no funcionaría; sólo te traería la fila con la menor edad dentro de las filas con el mismo nombre de alumno, por lo tanto, te traerá una fila por cada alumno que tenga nombre distinto. La segunda forma no sé por qué la agregas si dices que no es recomendable; sólo funcionaría si se asume que un solo alumno tiene la edad menor; si hay dos con la edad mínima se mostraría uno solo.

Comment: Te entiendo, sin embargo si lees mi post dice claramente: "Me parece que lo que buscas es algo así "; no le estoy dando la respuesta exacta, porque no tengo información suficiente como puedes ver. lo ideal seria tener una fecha de nacimiento con horas minutos y segundos. Así se podría saber exactamente el menor.

Comment: No creo que el "algo así" sea excusa para dar una respuesta a medias que da un resultado que no sirve; me parece más probable que confundas a quien hizo la pregunta en vez de aclararle las cosas y acercarlo a la respuesta.

Comment: La primera arrojaría N resultados, por tanto es una respuesta incorrecta. Me queda la duda: por qué la segunda opción no es recomendable?

Comment: @amenadiel La segunda opción no es recomendable, al menos de la forma en que yo lo entiendo, porque si hay dos o más estudiantes que compartan la edad menor, sólo se mostraría uno.

Comment: Muchachos di con la siguiente sintaxis, la guarda sin problema pero al ejecutarla me dice que "the used select statement have a different number of columns"

Comment: delimiter //


CREATE FUNCTION estujoven() RETURNS   int

deterministic 

BEGIN 

DECLARE edadest int;

SELECT nom_est, MIN(edad_est)
INTO edadest 
FROM
 estudiante;

RETURN edadest;

END

//

Comment: @CamiloDuran explicanos bien que estas tratando de hacer... puesto que la respuesta de rodrigo cumple el requisito de traer la menor edad. y en que lenguaje de base de datos estas trabajando.